# Index a directory of geotif files

Tags: python, geotiff, rasterio

I have a directory of many GeoTIFF files that are tiles of global map. Is there a python module that can index such a directory and then provide access to the data using coordinates in the respective CRS? Say I have a coordinate or polygon, I would like the module to return the file(s) that contain the coordinate/polygon.

Comment: Can you show an example of GeoTIFF with directory name and files name?

Comment: It's these tifs https://zenodo.org/record/7254221#.Y34VWNLMKV4

Comment: rasterio module can help u

Comment: @ElvinJafarov can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a good solution. One can create a raster file from any directory of `.tif` using the SAGA library: https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/7.1.1/io_gdal_8.html

Example: `saga_cmd io_gdal 8 -DIRECTORY ./sierra_nevada_parts -CATALOGUE_CGS sierra_nevada_parts/raster`

Answer (score 1):

you can use rastterio in these steps:

1. Install 'rasterio' using pip:

- pip install rasterio

2. then :

   import rasterio

   with rasterio.open('path/to/geotiff.tif') as src:
   # Access the raster data ...
3. Use the 'bounds' property of the 'rasterio.DatasetReader' object to get the bounding box of the GeoTIFF file in its native CRS:

   ````py
   with rasterio.open('path/to/geotiff.tif') as src:
       print(src.bounds)  # (left, bottom, right, top)
   ```
   ````
4. Use the 'rasterio.transform.xy()' function to convert spatial coordinates from one CRS to another:

   ````py
   from rasterio.transform import xy

   x, y = xy(src.transform, lon, lat)
   ```
   ````
5. Use the `rasterio.windows.from_bounds()` function to create a `Window` object that covers the area of interest in the GeoTIFF file based on its bounding box:

   ''''python
   from rasterio.windows import from_bounds

   window = from_bounds(left, bottom, right, top, src.transform)
   '''
6. Use the `rasterio.DatasetReader.read()` method to read the data from the GeoTIFF file within the specified `Window` object:

   ```py
   data = src.read(window=window)
   ```

'''

You can repeat above steps  for all the GeoTIFF files in your directory and store the bounding boxes and file paths in a lookup table or index. Then, when you have a spatial coordinate or polygon, you can use the 'bounds' property of the coordinate or polygon to look up the GeoTIFF files that contain the area of interest, and use the methods above to read the data from those files.

Comment: This answer looks like slightly edited ChatGPT

Comment: @DavidW that is what I thought too.

Answer (score 1):

The file name indicated where is it.

Example:

```
ESA_WorldCover_10m_2021_v200_S33E114_Map.tif
```

South 33° and East 114° from [Null Island](https://blogs.loc.gov/maps/2016/04/the-geographical-oddity-of-null-island/#:%7E:text=Null%20Island%20is%20an%20imaginary,Equator%20meets%20the%20Prime%20Meridian.) or (latitude= 0°N, longitude = 0°E)

Google map show degree grids

```
https://earth.google.com/web/@23.8699403,0.84901336,-4677.47560475a,8561159.36951995d,35y,4.65926929h,0t,0r
```

[image]

And [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library can get the detail coordinate from GeoTIFF file.

This code can get the file list from Polygon.

```py
import rasterio
import os
from geojson import Polygon

# check point is within rectangle
def rectContains(rect, point):
    logic = rect[0] < point[0] < rect[2] and rect[1] < point[1] < rect[3]
    return logic

directory = "./{0}".format("ESA_WorldCover_10m_2021_v200_60deg_macrotile_S90E060")

# get all of file's name
file_list = os.listdir(directory)
items = []
for file_name in file_list:
    file_path = "{0}/{1}".format(directory, file_name)
    with rasterio.open(file_path) as dt:
        item = {
            "file": file_name,
            "rect": ([dt.bounds.left, dt.bounds.bottom, dt.bounds.right, dt.bounds.top])
        }
        items.append(item)


# looking polygon coordinate list, format (latitude, longitude)
polygon = Polygon(
    [
        [
            (73.0, -51.3),
            (115.5, -32.7)
        ]
    ]
)

# getting the selected geoTIFF files
selected_tiff_files = []
for point in polygon['coordinates'][0]:
    for item in items:
        if (rectContains(item['rect'], point)):
            selected_tiff_files.append(item['file'])

# print selected files
for tiff_file in selected_tiff_files:
    print(tiff_file)
```

Demo files from [ESA_WorldCover](https://zenodo.org/record/7254221#.Y34VWNLMKV4) the [ESA_WorldCover_10m_2021_v200_60deg_macrotile_S90E060.zip](https://zenodo.org/record/7254221/files/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2021_v200_60deg_macrotile_S90E060.zip?download=1)
[image]

Result

```
$ python get-file-names.py
ESA_WorldCover_10m_2021_v200_S54E072_Map.tif
ESA_WorldCover_10m_2021_v200_S33E114_Map.tif
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works. I was looking for a general method though. Given a directory of .tif list the intersecting segments.

Comment: Thanks to hearing it works, you can expand to support multiple directories by scanning all of sub directories. Can you add to accept for me?

Comment: I am aware that the example does contain information about what section of the world it contains. I was looking for a solution that works for any directory of tifs. And I was wondering whether a library already implements this, that is, take a directory as input and then have that functionality.

Comment: Any directory to find matched directory, not  support by `rasterio` library. Do you want to scan directories capability by my code?

Comment: Yes, one could implement this. As written in the original question I wondering whether a library like rasterio or rioxarray or geopandas etc already does this.

Comment: I will try to update my code after return from work. Today is not a holiday.